# add multiple languages to tinymce in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, localization, tinymce

In our project we used tinymce from creating moxiecode tinymce dll.
    I added `fr.xml` and `fr.js` files to related langs folder in tinymce folder.
    And modified code like below in Language.aspx page which is in langs folder of   imagemanager plugin in tinymce folder.

```
  string langfr = "fr';  
                LanguagePack langPack = man.LangPack;  
                langPack.Load(this.MapPath(@"im/" + langfr + ".xml"));  
                         Moxiecode.Manager.Utils.GroupCollection groups = langPack.Languages[langfr].Groups;
```

and modified `"en"` language selection to `"fr"`.

Is this the right way to add another language to tinymce

I followed the above implementation like in the [site](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26457)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one langugage per editor instance. Each instance can get its own language-setting using a different tinymce configuration for each editor instance.